# How to get latest value from Native Druid query?

Tags: database, apache, open-source, store, druid

There are duplicate records in my Druid DB, when we fire Druid Native Query, we get more than one records (duplicate records), my queryType is scan.

I need to see only one record/result through my Native Druid Query, how can I get one record out of n duplicate records?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a groupBy query. A [scan query](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/scan-query) will return all your data. If you use a [groupBy](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/groupbyquery) Query, you can supply the dimensions of the records you want to select. They will only be returned once, as they are grouped by.

Comment: and you can use the LATEST aggregate function to get the most recent value of columns you are not grouping on.